# Uploading a file over FTPS

Tags: curl

I need to automatically upload an excel file to a FTPS server.  Right now I'm using curl but if there is a better option out there, I'm all ears.

What I have so far:

```
curl -k --data-binary --ftp-ssl -T "/path/to/file.xlsx" ftp://user:pass@www.web.com
```

This will create an entry on the server but the Excel file will be blank.  Which is obviously not the intended result.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
curl --upload-file uploadfile http://www.example.com/somefile.xslx
```

if you have a mechanism for [PUT](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#PUT)